# css z-index pointer-events

Tags: jquery, css

So my problem is, I want to be able to click through the `.row` because it's width fills the window but not the `.fourcol` because that has content like links and images. Is there something I'm missing with CSS? or can I achieve this with jquery?

My CSS and HTML is like this:

```
<div class="container >
   <div class="row">
     <div class="fourcol>
       <p>Content</p>
     </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Then I have something underneath

```
<div class="drag">
<img src="image.png"/>
</div>
```

With the CSS:

```
.row {
width: 100%;
max-width: 1240px;
min-width: 755px;
overflow: hidden;
z-index: 1;
}

.fourcol {
z-index: 3;
}
```

Then I position `.drag` with `position: absolute;` and `z-index: 2;` just near `<p>content</p>`

Thanks heaps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

z-index only works when there is a position property. So the z-index for `.row` will do nothing. You need to add `position: relative;` as a minimum. Then adding the `.drag` div inside the `.fourcol` div with the higher z-index, should cause it to come forward. Although you may need to use a value higher than 2.

Comment: That all seems to work well here in Chrome. White elements above the background, but behind the text.

Comment: Thanks I hope I don't run into any usability problems.

Comment: I just wanted to toss in a link that discusses z-index and overlay to great length. It really helped me in getting a solid grasp in understanding how stacking works. -> http://css-discuss.incutio.com/wiki/Overlapping_And_ZIndex